# module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_get_notAfter'

Tags: nginx, openssl, certbot

I have installed certbot before was working fine with ngix plugin but now I cant install certificate or renew one bellow are log

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/bin/certbot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('certbot==0.40.0', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1382, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1128, in run
    should_get_cert, lineage = _find_cert(config, domains, certname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 287, in _find_cert
    action, lineage = _find_lineage_for_domains_and_certname(config, domains, certname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 314, in _find_lineage_for_domains_and_certname
    return _find_lineage_for_domains(config, domains)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 264, in _find_lineage_for_domains
    return _handle_identical_cert_request(config, ident_names_cert)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 196, in _handle_identical_cert_request
    if renewal.should_renew(config, lineage):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 278, in should_renew
    if lineage.should_autorenew():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/storage.py", line 943, in should_autorenew
    expiry = crypto_util.notAfter(self.version(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/crypto_util.py", line 432, in notAfter
    return _notAfterBefore(cert_path, crypto.X509.get_notAfter)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/crypto_util.py", line 451, in _notAfterBefore
    timestamp = method(x509)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1407, in get_notAfter
    return self._get_boundary_time(_lib.X509_get_notAfter)
```

AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_get_notAfter'
2022-01-27 06:41:35,768:ERROR:certbot.log:An unexpected error occurred:

Answer (score -2):

Install Certbot through SNAP, as per instructions on https://certbot.eff.org/instructions